# Парсинг json средствами python, модуль json

Tags: python, json, парсер

Задача рандомно парсить комментарии, но как это сделать без идентификатора каждого из них?

```py
import json

jsonData = """
{
    "thread": "usb",
    "comment_page": [
        {
            "comment": "Комментарий 1",
            "views": 679
        },

        {
            "comment": "Комментарий 2",
            "views": 1882
        },

        {
            "comment": "Комментарий 3",
            "views": 574
        },

        {
            "comment": "Комментарий 4",
            "views": 574
        },

        {
            "comment": "Комментарий 5",
            "views": 19
        },

        {
            "comment": "Комментарий 6",
            "views": 295
        }
    ]
}
"""

dictData = json.loads(jsonData)
print(dictData["comment"])
```

Comment: И какой же комментарий вы считаете определенным?

Comment: Извиняюсь, не правильно описал. Требуется рандомом выбрать один коммент из всех.

Comment: Используйте ```random.choice()```в который передавать надо список по ключу ```comment_page```

Comment: @Nobody Почему не оформлено как ответ? ))

Comment: @Nobody пожалуйста опишите подробнее. Как бы не передавал, ругается на строковый тип данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

jsonData = ... # ваш json
dictData = json.loads(jsonData)

print(random.choice(dictData['comment_page']))  # выбрать рандом комментарий
                                # {'comment': 'Комментарий 4', 'views': 574}
```

дальше этот словарь парсите как надо.